# What is the difference between simple, highQuality, balanced for textBreakStrategy property in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

What is the difference between `simple`, `highQuality` and `balanced` value for `textBreakStrategy` property of `<Text>` component in React Native? These values are not documented in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#textbreakstrategy) of React Native.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default, for `Text` component `Android` use `highQuality` and that is causing the words breaking using hyphens.

If you want to avoid that, you can set the break strategy to `simple`.

This is the difference among all of `textBreakStrategy`s.

> **balanced** - Line breaking strategy balances line lengths.
>
> **high_quality** - Line breaking uses high-quality strategy, including
> hyphenation.
>
> **simple**     - Line breaking uses simple strategy.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any difference between balanced and high_quality.

Comment: @Tapani it depends on a text which you are dealing with. Try with different content and text versions and see if there is some difference.

Answer (score 0):

For `highQuality` I observed the first break happening midway i.e in between the words.

[image]

For `simple` the first word break was proper and then it happened midway

[image]

So when would you need 'simple'?

In my case combining `numberOfLines={2}` with `simple` `textBreakingStrategy` was the optimum way to handle multi line breaks.

[image]